# Triangle with two rounded sides

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I'm attempting to create a triangle, but **with rounded sides**. And I mean sides, not corners. The reason for this is that the triangle is meant to resemble animal ears. I can't, however, figure out how I'd make the sides not be, well, straight. I'd like a CSS-only solution, if possible.

If you need a picture, this is kinda what I'm going for.

[image: Triangle with 2 rounded sides]

I've managed to get [this far](https://jsfiddle.net/gupLk2aq/), but I'm not sure where to go next.

```css
.e1 {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 75px 200px 75px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #f7882e transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="e1"></div>
```

I tried messing around with `:before` and `:after`, but I think I messed up, because I can't even get it to show up despite giving it a set width/height and a block display... So again, not sure where to go.

Comment: @dippas You clearly didn't read what I asked. I specifically said I don't want the corners to be rounded.

Comment: Check [this site](http://cssround.com/). Very cool and can be a help for this type of idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Using CSS:**

The best that you could achieve with CSS would be something like the below. The shape construction is as follows:

- A pseudo-element whose border-radius is 100% on all sides except border-top-right-radius. This produces a leaf like shape. This is then rotated by -45deg so that the tip is towards the top.
- This pseudo element is then positioned such that only half of it is visible (by setting `overflow` as `hidden` on the parent).
- The parent container's Y axis is then rotated by a high angle to kind of compress the shape. This makes it look more like an arrow.

The shape is responsive but as you can see its creation is very tricky and this is why CSS is not the right tool for this job. **SVG is the correct tool** and a demo is available below.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid tomato;
  overflow: hidden; /* hide the parts that are not required */
  transform: rotateY(65deg); /* to compress the shape in Y axis */
}
div:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 0px;
  top: 50%; /* positioning to make only part of it visible */
  height: calc(100% - 6px); /* to offset for the border width */
  width: calc(100% - 6px); /* to offset for the border width */
  border-radius: 100% 0% 100% 100%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  border: 3px solid tomato; /* made thicker because the transform will make it look thinner than normal */
}

/* just for demo */

div {transition: all 1s ease;}
div:hover {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

**Using SVG:** <sup>recommended</sup>

With SVG we can create this shape using a single `path` element and a couple of Quadratic Curve-to (`Q`) commands. It is very simple, scalable (responsive), allows us greater control over the curvature etc.

SVG commands used and explanation:

- `M` - moves the imaginary pen to the point specified by the coordinates.
- `Q` - Draws a quadratic curve from the current position of the pen to the point that is indicated by the second set of coordinates that follow the `Q` command. The first set of coordinates represent the control point. This control point determines the slope of the curve.
- `z` - Closes the shape by drawing a straight line from the current pen position to the starting point.

The SVG shape can also be rotated just like a normal CSS element.

```css
svg {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: tomato;
  stroke-width: 1;
}

/* just for demo */

svg {
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
svg:hover {
  transform: rotate(-15deg);
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 105 105" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <path d="M15,102 Q25,50 50,0 Q75,50 85,102z" />
</svg>
```

The above is just a basic implementation. You can play around with the control points of the Quadratic curve to get different slopes. Below are a few possible samples:

```
<path d="M15,102 Q25,35 50,0 Q75,35 85,102z" />
<path d="M15,102 Q20,35 50,0 Q80,35 85,102z" />
```

---

Another advantage of using SVG for such shapes is that you can easily add a ***gradient or an image as fill or background*** to the shape. Below is a demo:

```css
svg {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: tomato;
  stroke-width: 1;
}
path#image {
  fill: url(#bg-image);
}
path#gradient {
  fill: url(#bg-grad);
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 105 105" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="bg-image" width="1" height="1" patternUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <image xlink:href="https://placeimg.com/200/200/nature" width="105" height="105" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <path d="M15,102 Q20,35 50,0 Q80,35 85,102z" id="image" />
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 105 105" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <defs>
    <radialGradient id="bg-grad" width="1" height="1" patternUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#3F9CBA" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#153346" />
    </radialGradient>
  </defs>
  <path d="M15,102 Q20,35 50,0 Q80,35 85,102z" id="gradient" />
</svg>
```

Comment: With `SVG` looks better.

Comment: @Ullas: Yep, SVGs are much better for shapes like these. I wanted to show the CSS first up just to show OP how difficult it is with CSS and we still get a lower quality output compared to SVG.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up using SVG after seeing someone else's work with it. I'm kind of a newbie to it, but I think I have down what I wanted. Thank you~

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach to draw this shape.

1. Create a `div` with specific `width`, `height` and `border-bottom` values.
2. Add `overflow: hidden` so that excess part may be hidden from view.
3. Use `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements to draw large ellipses and adjust values so that they meet at a common point.

**Output Image:**

[image: Output Image]

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

div {
  border-bottom: 2px solid orange;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 400px;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 20px;
}

div:before,
div:after {
  border: 2px solid orange;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  bottom: -150%;
  height: 300%;
  content: '';
  width: 396%;
  left: 0;
}

div:after {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt!

```css
.e1 {
  width: 124px;
  height: 160px;
  background: #f7882e;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 100% 100% 0 0 / 200% 200% 0 0;
  margin: 60px;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
 }
 .e1:before {
   content:"";
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   margin: 0 auto;
   top: -39px;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-left: 46px solid transparent;
   border-right: 46px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 91px solid #f7882e;
 }
```

```html
<div class="e1"></div>
```

Comment: Hm... Would there be a way to make it run up to the top corner, do you think? Either way, this does give some more direction ^^ Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "run up to the top corner?"

Comment: http://prntscr.com/dxikb6 See where the arrow points? It kinda comes into the triangle there, instead of the very top. Wonder if I should try a path code for this instead...